# Dropbox Authentication Store Retreival

Tags: android, kivy, dropbox-api, buildozer

I want my app users to upload documents to a common dropbox account. My app is developed in kivy. In the `main.py`, dropbox authecation token is present . Once compile it using `buildozer` to `.apk` . Is there some way a user can get hold of the token from the `.apk` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (advanced) user can decompile your `.apk` and read the source code. You need to do code obfuscation (e.g. with proguard) to protect your source code.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)
- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531187/android-and-obfuscation
- [How to hide python code file and other related files in a kivy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252729/how-to-hide-python-code-file-and-other-related-files-in-a-kivy-project)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't use native android SDK. My code is in Python. How can I do this provided just with .apk file.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia since python is a runtime-interpreted language, it is very difficult (but not impossible!) to protect the code. See here for the discussion you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252729/how-to-hide-python-code-file-and-other-related-files-in-a-kivy-project

Comment: Thanks for reponse, in my case I just to hide one string that is the authentication code without much or any importance to the rest of the code.

Comment: How about storing the authentication code in another file and reading from it.

Comment: If someone really wants to get at the code, just having it in a file will not really deter them. We usually suggest that a good way to start obfuscating python on android is to cythonise it, and maybe you can combine that with some direct obfuscation tools.

Comment: @inclement Can you provide an example on how to cythonise given just reading string from file is the concern.